# Can you add where clauses to a model based on an environment variable in dbt?

Tags: sql, model, environment-variables, where-clause, dbt

I would like to be able to add a conditional to a model based on the environment variable.

Something like:

```
SELECT ....
FROM ....
WHERE env_var = {{ env_var('DBT_VAR') }}
```

That way I can run this model for all my target schemas but have a where clause that allows me to do something different for a specific environment variable. So, if I had 4 different environment variables that all need the same model, but 2 of them needed an extra where clause, I wouldn't have to re-write the model 4 times... I could just use one and it would run depending on the environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work exactly as you've written it, assuming you have a field in your model also called env_var.

You could also branch using an `if` statement, based on an env var or `target.name`:

```sql
SELECT ....
FROM ....
{% if target.name != 'prod' %}
WHERE date_field > current_timestamp - interval '1 month'
{% endif %}
```

UPDATE:

You can also compare the `target` to a variable, if you'd rather not hard-code that. You can use either `var` or `env_var` -- the approach is very similar:

```sql
SELECT ....
FROM ....
{% if target.name != env_var('PROD_TARGET') %}
WHERE date_field > current_timestamp - interval '1 month'
{% endif %}
```

Or if you just want to check if an `env_var` is set:

```sql
SELECT ....
FROM ....
{% if env_var('THIS_IS_PROD') is not None %}
WHERE date_field > current_timestamp - interval '1 month'
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! I do not currently have an env_var field, but I could set env_var or target.name to an environment variable like {{ env_var('DBT_VAR') }} ?

Comment: sure! Answer updated with another example that compares `target.name` to an `env_var`